# Defining a loop within a script inside package.json

Tags: bash, loops, npm, package.json

Is it possible to include a for loop inside a package.json file to recurse into subdirectories and execute a command in each:

```
# .env File
DIRECTORIES="Dir1, Dir2"
```

```
# package.json file in parent directory
"scripts": {
  "install-all-inefficient": "(cd ./dir/Dir1/ && npm install) && (cd ./dir/Dir2/ && npm install)",
  "install-all-ideal": ". .env && functionToLoopThroughDirectoriesDefinedInEnvironmentVariables",
},
```

I was looking at this: [Defining an array as an environment variable in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552125/defining-an-array-as-an-environment-variable-in-node-js) as an example for defining the array, and then trying to somehow use `process.env.DIRECTORIES` to create a loop without writing too much ugly bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
"install-all-ideal": ". .env; for dir in \"${DIRECTORIES[@]}\"; do (cd \"$dir\" && npm install); done"
```

with .env :

```
DIRECTORIES=("Dir1" "Dir2")
```

Comment: This is almost there, (I didn't know about the `@` which is helpful). Unfortunately, `DIRECTORIES` is still a string of comma separated variables, so I need to find a way of splitting them.. was thinking maybe: `array=(\`echo $string | sed 's/,/\n/g'\`)`, but I'm getting bad substitution errors